# FlexBox (React Native) layout problem: How to vertically align items on 2 seperate lines

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am working with FlexBox in React Native and I currently have a View with 2 lines as follow:
[current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLIIl.png)

What I would like to do, is align vertically A1 and B1 as follow

[desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFrOc.png)

How can I do such a thing ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to leave the same amount of `paddingLeft` on both Views. But on the second View you set `justifyContent: "space-between"`

Comment: Yes I've tried that, but I don't want space-between because in landscape mode on device, the layout is less pretty. I'd like to have spaces on the sides of the second line

Comment: @AlixHumbert you can have  equal padding for left and right for the Second View, it can be a percentage of the available width, so it looks pretty for both Portrait and Landscape

Comment: so there is no way to have equal spacing like provided by space-evenly ?